# How can I create Local Loopback on Linux?

Tags: networking, ethernet

I need to create local loopback as shown herein: [Performing Loopback Testing for Fast Ethernet and Gigabit Ethernet Interfaces](http://www.juniper.net/techpubs/en_US/junos14.1/topics/topic-map/ethernet-fast-and-gigabit-loopback-testing.html#id-11863133).

*Excerpt*

> #### Configure a Local Loopback Action
>
> To configure a local loopback without physically connecting the
>   transmit port to the receive port, follow these steps:
>
> 1. In configuration mode, go to the following hierarchy level:
>
>    [edit]
>
>    user@host# edit interfaces interface-name (fastether-options |
>      gigether-options)
> 2. Configure the local loopback:
>
>    [edit interfaces interface-name (fastether-options | gigether-options)]
>
>    user@host# set loopback

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is their documentation on interface creation, titled: [Red Hat Enterprise Linux 3: Reference Guide - Chapter 8. Network Interfaces](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/3/html/Reference_Guide/s1-networkscripts-interfaces.html).

1. Add this line if it does not exist to `/etc/hosts`

   ```
   127.0.0.1       localhost       localhost.localdomain
   ```
2. run the following commands as root

   ```
   # ifconfig lo 127.0.0.1

   # route add 127.0.0.1
   ```
3. Test the interface

   ```
   # ifconfig lo
   lo    Link encap:Local Loopback
         inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
         UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:3924  Metric:1
         RX packets:60 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
         TX packets:60 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
         collisions:0 txqueuelen:0

   # ping localhost
   PING localhost (127.0.0.1): 56 data bytes
   64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=255 time=0.3 ms
   64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=255 time=0.2 ms
   64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=255 time=0.1 ms
   64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=255 time=0.1 ms
   64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=4 ttl=255 time=0.2 ms
   64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=5 ttl=255 time=0.1 ms

   --- localhost ping statistics ---
   6 packets transmitted, 6 packets received, 0% packet loss
   round-trip min/avg/max = 0.1/0.1/0.3 ms
   ```

Comment: Note that in virtually all distributions worth the name, loopback is already configured out of the box.